# How to prove Shannon entropy inequality with something that seems to be some sort of taylor expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I'm slightly confused about some sort of "proof" (probably not a real proof since it's physics math) 
I have the formula

$f(x) = f(y) + (x-y)f'(y) + \frac{f''(y)}{2\epsilon}, \quad \epsilon \in (x,y)$

f(x) = -x lnx rewritten in the formula becomes
$f(x) = -x \ln y -x+y - \frac{1}{2\epsilon}$

Which somehow can be used to prove that the Shannon entropy 
$S(\vec{p}) = -\sum_i^n p_i \ln p_i \leq \ln n$ And I can't simply see how I will do it.
Someone who know which obvious step I'm missing or if the professor simply has done some writing error? (wouldn't be the fist time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your professor used $y=1/n$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so, is it correct if I end up with  the lagrange multiplier? And is  lagrange multiplier seen as stronger method for proving $S(\vec{p}) \leq ln n$  than the proof with Jensen's inequality? (I'm usually doing applied physics so I'm not that familiar with knowing what is strong and week proofs, theorems etc)

Comment: I dont understand where suddenly a Lagrange multiplier is coming from. If you just insert $x=p_i$ and $y=1/n$ you end up with the right hand side.

Comment: a Lagrange multiplier can be used to find the maximal value of $S(\vec{p})$ which is $\ln n$.  Thanks.

Comment: Yo gave 3 options to come to the same conclusion. 1. Maximize the sum directly under constraints. 2. Estimate each term seperately using the given inequality. 3. Use Jensen's inequality.

Comment: For the second option you need to rigorosly proof the inequality first, that's why I would personally prefer the first option.